# Swift 5 - UIButtons Side by side in tableView footer with original separator line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, tableview

I am trying to add **two buttons** programmatically side by side (on the bottom left) in the **tableView footer.**

The issue that I am having is that I have to manually draw the separator line when defining the tableView footer because the separator line disappears.

How can I simply **add two buttons** to the bottom left of the tableView footer **without** loosing the original separator line?

```
var terms_button = UIButton()
var policy_button = UIButton()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        //terms button
        terms_button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        terms_button.setTitle("Terms", for: .normal)
        terms_button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        terms_button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.roboto(size: 12, weight: .medium)
        terms_button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.38
        terms_button.addTarget(self,action: #selector(didTapTermsButton),for: .touchUpInside)
        
        //policy button
        policy_button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        policy_button.setTitle("Privacy Policy", for: .normal)
        policy_button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        policy_button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.roboto(size: 12, weight: .medium)
        policy_button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.38
        policy_button.addTarget(self,action: #selector(didTapPolicyButton),for: .touchUpInside)

        let result = UIView()

            // recreate insets from existing ones in the table view
            let insets = tableView.separatorInset
            let width = tableView.bounds.width - insets.left - insets.right
            let sepFrame = CGRect(x: insets.left, y: -0.5, width: width, height: 0.5)

            // create layer with separator, setting color
            let sep = CALayer()
            sep.frame = sepFrame
            sep.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
            result.layer.addSublayer(sep)
            result.addSubview(policy_button)
            result.addSubview(terms_button)

            return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning your own `let result = UIView()` view instance from `viewForFooterInSection`, you are discarding the original built-in default view provided by the iOS.

What you can attempt is -

1. delete the `viewForFooterInSection` implementation
2. try to use default built-in view provided by iOS
3. try to customize default view's appearance like following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    guard let footerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    
    let contentView = footerView.contentView
    // Try adding your buttons to this `contentView` 
}
```

This is the only way to try to keep using built-in view with possible customizations. If this doesn't work reliably across different iOS versions, you would need to go back to `viewForFooterInSection` custom view implementation.